# Two 4D mat mul numpy and should expect output 5D

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, 4d

I want to apply attention weights (5 label) to my convolution with 3 filters, could any help me to do how to apply matmul. Appreciated if you give tensorflow version as well.

```
import numpy as np
conv = np.random.randint(10,size=[1,3,2,2], dtype=int) # [batches,filter,row,col]
attention = np.random.randint(5,size=[1,5,2,1], dtype=int) # [batches,label,row,col]
np.matmul(conv,attention).shape # expected output size [1,3,5,2,1] [batches,filter,label,row,col]
```

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (1,3,2,2)->(1,3,2,newaxis,2) (1,5,2,1)->(1,5,newaxis,1,2)
```

Comment: `dot` and `matmul` normally involves summing on one pair of axes.  It's not clear from the desired shape whether that's happening or not.  You could get that shape with broadcasted elementwise multiplication without any sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs of [`matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

and

> Stacks of matrices are broadcast together as if the matrices were elements.

This means that in your case, all but the last two dimensions need to match up. If you want the output shape to be `1, 3, 5, 2, 1`, you will need to explicitly insert an empty axis into each array. You can do that at creation time:

```
import numpy as np
conv = np.random.randint(10, size=[1, 3, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int)
attention = np.random.randint(5, size=[1, 1, 5,2,1], dtype=int)
np.matmul(conv,attention).shape
```

Alternatively, you can make the insertion explicit by multiplying views with the appropriate insertions:

```
np.matmul(conv[:, :, np.newaxis, ...], attention[:, np.newaxis, ...]).shape
```

Comment: Thank you, could you give more options like np.tensordot and np.einsum if possible because i have to deal with more number of filter's and labels.

Comment: @user1531248. That will be left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: `tensordot` doesn't give you good control over the non-summed dimensions.